# How to pass authenticated user to a new view with Node JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

The flow of my application is to use NodeJS/Express and React to login, create a user who has a JWT token, and then hit authorized routes on the application. As i'm a bit new to this, i'm having trouble understanding how to leverage the user I just created at the signup page and then having that user pushed to a homepage where I could still grab his information. Here is some boiler plate

CREATE A USER
The req.body in this case will be something like { username: me, email: me@test.com, password: hashed_pw }

```
router.post('/users', async (req, res) => {
    const user = new User(req.body)

    try {
        await user.save()
        const token = await user.generateAuthToken()

        res.status(201).send({user: user, token: token})
    } catch (e) {
        res.send({"error": "Unable to create"})

    }

})
```

AUTH MIDDLEWARE

```
const auth = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ', '')
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, 'mysecret')
        const user = await User.findOne({ _id: decoded._id, 'tokens.token': token })

        if (!user) {
            throw new Error()
        }
        console.log('user', user)
        req.token = token 
        req.user = user
        next()
    } catch (e) {
        // res.status(401).send({ error: 'Please authenticate.' })
        res.send({ error: 'Please authenticate.' })

    }
}
```

The backend route for the "homepage" - note the "auth" middleware method is run first. The auth method will return the user in the req

```
router.get('/users/me', auth, async (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user)
})
```

On the front end - i would have a simple login

```
export default function SignUp(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('')
  const [error, setError] = useState(false)

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password === confirmPassword){
        const newUser = {
            name,
            email,
            password
        }
        axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users', newUser)
        .then( (res) => 
        localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(res.data.user), 
        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(res.data.token))
        ))
        props.history.push("/journal")
        } else {
        setError(true)
        setName('')
        setEmail('')
        setPassword('')
        setConfirmPassword('')
      }
    }


  return ( 
         <div> My login form </div>
          )
```

And then it would redirect to a homepage - here is where I lose the logged in users info

```
function BlogEntryGatePage(){
    const [user, setUser] = useState('')

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
          const getUser = await axios('http://localhost:4000/users/me')
          console.log(getUser)
        }
        fetchData();
      });

    return(
        <div>
            Post Login form - the /users/me route above is called when             
            this component runs but i automatically hit the auth error.


        </div>
    )

}
```

The way my logic is constructed, i need to hit the 'users/me' route as an authenticated user but as soon as react creates me and pushes me to the next component, my axios call to 'users/me' does not work anymore.

I'm not sure what to do to fix!

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways you could do this - basically you need some kind of elevated/shared application state.

You could store the JWT in localstorage and get/decode it in each page.

You could use the Context API + react hooks to save the user details after login and fetch them on the next page